# Spring-kafka-listener: Offsets remain after last message using manual acknowledge

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

in my current project I'm using spring-kafka to send, transform and retrieve messages. The producer sends messages of type *A* to a kafka-topic *topic-A*, then a kafka-streams instance reads the messages of type *A* from this topic, maps it to type *B* and writes those mapped messages to the kafka-topic *topic-B*. Finally a kafka-listener listens on topic *topic-B* and persists those messages to an elasticsearch-instance.

The listener is working in batch-mode and is configured for manual acknowledgment. The batch is acknowledged after the contained messages have been successfully persistet to elasticsearch.

This works quite well, except for one edge-case:
After the producer has finished sending messages (it's a test-setup) and the listener has retrieved, persisted and acknowledged the last batch, there is still a lag for consumers in the consumer-group:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| group               topic       partition    current-offset  log-end-offset  lag   consumer-id  host        client-id |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| consumer-group1     topic-B     2            335681           335690           9     consumer2  /172.18.0.1   client2 |
| consumer-group1     topic-B     9                 0                0           0     consumer9  /172.18.0.1   client9 |
| consumer-group1     topic-B     6            537082           537085           3     consumer6  /172.18.0.1   client6 |
| consumer-group1     topic-B     8            394747           394752           5     consumer8  /172.18.0.1   client8 |
| consumer-group1     topic-B     7            584215           584225          10     consumer7  /172.18.0.1   client7 |
| consumer-group1     topic-B     1                 0                0           0    consumer10  /172.18.0.1  client10 |
| consumer-group1     topic-B     5                 0                0           0     consumer5  /172.18.0.1   client5 |
| consumer-group1     topic-B     0           1089342          1089350           8     consumer1  /172.18.0.1   client1 |
| consumer-group1     topic-B     4                 0                0           0     consumer4  /172.18.0.1   client4 |
| consumer-group1     topic-B     3                 0                0           0     consumer3  /172.18.0.1   client3 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tested this with ack-mode *MANUAL_IMMEDIATE* as well as *MANUAL*, the results are the same, the consumer lag never reduces after the last batch has been retrieved by the listener.

In my tests I also tried the same thing using a vanilla-kafka-consumer. With this approach, the consumer-lags are as expected (=0) after the last batch has been acknowledged.

This is very confusing, since I use the same kafka-configuration for both approaches, so I suspect it has something to do with spring-kafka.
Has anyone experienced the same problem, and if so how did  you solve it?
Any help is much appreciated!

### Config

```
spring:
  kafka:
    listener:
      ack-mode: MANUAL # MANUAL_IMMEDIATE
      concurrency:  10
    consumer:
      client-id: "b-consumer-client-local"
      group-id: "b-consumer-group-local"
      bootstrap-servers: "localhost:9092"
      # key-deserializer: "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
      # value-deserializer: "org.myproject.serialization.BDeserializer"
      # auto-commit-interval: 1000
      # auto-offset-reset: "earliest"
      enable-auto-commit: false
      # fetch-max-wait: 500
      # fetch-min-size: 1
      # heartbeat-interval: 3000
      # max-poll-records: 5000
```

### Listener-Config

```
@Configuration
public class ListenerConfiguration {
    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Autowired
    public ListenerConfiguration(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        this.kafkaProperties = kafkaProperties;
    }


    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, B> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(),
                                                new StringDeserializer(),
                                                new BDeserializer());
    }


    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        return new HashMap<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties());
    }


    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, B>
                kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, B> consumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, B> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConcurrency(kafkaProperties.getListener().getConcurrency());
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(kafkaProperties.getListener().getAckMode());
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

### Listener

```
@Component
public class TopicListener implements BatchAcknowledgingMessageListener<String, B> {
    private final String topic;

    TopicListener(TopicsConfiguration topicsConfiguration) {
        this.topic = topicsConfiguration.getInput();
    }

    @Override
    @KafkaListener(id = "batch-listener", topics = "#{__listener.getTopic()}")
    public void onMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<String, B>> list, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        if(saveData(list)) {
            acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        } 
    }

    private boolean saveData(List<ConsumerRecord<String, B>> list) {
        ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to show your `topic-B` consumer code and configuration.

Comment: "listens on topic topic-B and persists those messages to an elasticsearch-instance." .. And you're not using Kafka Connect for that because why?

Comment: @cricket_007 the kafka-cluster is hosted in the cloud and the vendor only supports kafka-2.3.0. the es-cluster is version 7.1, which is supported by kafka-connect-elasticsearch 5.4.0, which requires kafka-2.4.0

Comment: Kafka Connect doesn't require a certain version of Kafka. You can install Connect on your own servers / local machine even and configure for both endpoints. Feel free to create a new post or edit if you have issues doing that